# How to check a MTKView supports display-P3 pixel formats in macOS?

Tags: macos, metal, metalkit

I have a macOS app built in SwiftUI, where I have a custom view with an `MTKView`. I set the pixel format to be:

```swift
let metalView = MTKView()
metalView.colorPixelFormat = .bgra10_xr_srgb
```

This works on an M1 Mac mini running macOS Sonoma, and Xcode 15.

However, when I run the same code on a 2017 Intel MacBook Pro, on macOS Ventura (same Xcode 15), I get a runtime error and the view fails to initialize.

The log:

```
unsupported extended range format
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80611218a __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff805c3842b objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff806111ff0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 214
    3   QuartzCore                          0x00007ff80d94e5f5 -[CAMetalLayer setPixelFormat:] + 339
    4   MetalKit                            0x00007ff8173dd17a -[MTKView setColorPixelFormat:atIndex:] + 112
...
```

So it says the extended range pixel format (XR) is not supported. But how can I check that's the case?

The [bgra10_xr_srgb documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpixelformat/bgra10_xr_srgb)
doesn't mention anything about crashes. It says that if the device doesn't support the wider range, the color will get clamped, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XR formats are not available on anything other than `Apple3` GPU family and higher.

If you go to [Metal Feature Set Table](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) and scroll to `Extended range and wide color pixel formats`, you will see that it's only supported on `Apple3` and above.

So to check whether a device supports XR pixel formats, you would query `MTLDevice` by using `supportsFamily:MTLGPUFamilyApple3`